# Mapbox api error message: layer source not found

Tags: mapbox

We've been using MapBox Studio a lot and with joy and now we're trying to move things a little further by interacting with the mapbox api.

I'm trying to make a request to update a style to hide/show layers but I'm getting the error:

```
{
    "message": "layers[0]: source \"composite\" not found"
}
```

Here's my json body request payload:

```
{
   "version":8,
   "name":"OnStreet-V2",
   "layers":[
      {
         "id":"pay_ds-torres-vedras-livre",
         "type": "fill",
         "source": "composite",
         "source-layer": "Estacionamento_Livre",
         "layout":{
            "visibility":"none"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This is even stranger because to make sure I had the correct source and source-layer info, I downloaded json definition of my style from mapbox studio where I got the following info:

```
{
    "id": "pay_ds-torres-vedras-livre",
    "type": "fill",
    "source": "composite",
    "source-layer": "Estacionamento_Livre",
    "layout": {},
    `enter code here`"paint": {"fill-color": "hsl(101, 53%, 41%)", "fill-opacity": 0.3}
}
```

I've also done some research and couldn't find this specific issue. Also Source compositing is on in settings.

I'm using postman for testing the api calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you’re receiving is because your request’s style payload does not include a [“sources” parameter](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/) with a definition of the ‘composite’ source the style layer is referencing.

For example, the “sources” parameter in some of mapbox’s core styles looks like the following:

```json
“sources":
  {
    "composite":
      {
        "url":"mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8,mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2",
        "type":"vector"
      }
  }
```

This field is required as it will tell whatever rendering client you are using (GL JS, mobile SDK etc.) what data is necessary in order to properly render your style’s layers.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed missing. Now the request returns httpStatus ok (200), but, no change. I sent a request to set the layer visibility to none (hide the layer) but when I go back to the Mapbox Studio is still visible.